# Как получить значение href

Tags: jquery

У меня есть ссылка,

```
<a href='/projects/#mobile'></a>
$(a).click(function () {
var link = $(this).attr('href');
console.log(link); // /projects/#mobile
}
```

Я хочу получить только строку - `mobile` из переменной `link`
Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: `console.log(this.hash)` без всяких jQuery

Comment: И чем ему поможет `undefined` ?

Comment: @Zicrael какой undefined? https://jsfiddle.net/v27z7zkq/

Comment: Круто, не знал, спасибо:)

Comment: this.hash оставляет решетку

Comment: Мой ответ не оставляет :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если необходимо обрезать значение после `#` то например так:

```
const link = str.split('#')[1]; // mobile
```

До `#` так:

```
const befoteLink = str.split('#')[0]; // /projects/
```

**P.S** Вместо `#` можно использовать любой символ.

Answer (score 0):

Или так:

```
function get(url){
    let index = url.indexOf('#')+1;
    return url.substring(index);
}

console.log(get('/projects/#mobile'));
```